# WCF equivalent for OWIN/Katana in-memory integration testing

Tags: c#, wcf

For *OWIN/KATANA* in-memory hosting solution is available: *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost*. I'd like to find similar way for WCF services - integration tests which can be run in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just selfhosting the services?

[There are pretty good documentation for this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application)

```
// Create the ServiceHost.
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
{
    // Enable metadata publishing.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
    // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
    // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
    // by the service.
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the ServiceHost.
    host.Close();
}
```